# H-NMR Analysis of C15H24O

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nmr-spectroscopy, hydrogen, symmetry

[image]

I was able to figure out that the structure of this compound was a benzene ring with 2 equivalent trimethyl groups to give the 18H singlet. Another non-equivalent methyl group to give the 3H singlet. The singlet (integration of 1) from a hydroxyl group and the singlet at approx 6.9 ppm from hydrogens attached to the benzene. However, when assembling the molecule, I found that my structure was incorrect as it was not symmetrical, why is it a requirement that this molecule has to be symmetrical?

Comment: Hydroxyl? I don't think so. As for symmetry, why, you need the trimethyl groups to be equivalent, right?

Comment: Looks very much like a Ar-OH hydroxyl to me.

Comment: On second thought, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good fit for 2,6-di-*tert*-butyl-4-methylphenol. See the 1H spectrum [here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/2_6-ditert-butyl-4-methylphenol#section=1H-NMR-Spectra)